# How to access variables in the App.xaml resources dictionary in other xaml files?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, global-variables

Really quick one,

I have a small silverlight LOB application and in my App.xaml.cs i am adding an object to the app resources dictionary..

in C# I can access this in other classes by doing something like..

```
App.Current.Resources etc..
```

How would i access it in another xaml file?

i.e.

```
<TextBlock Text="{MyGlobalVariable}" />
```

Thanks

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too slow guys.. Answered my own question,

```
Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Source={StaticResource GlobalObject}}"
```